# MainActivity not resuming after navigating back from another activity

Tags: android

I have the following 2 activiteis:

1. MainActivity
2. TempActivity

**TempActivity**

```
public class TempActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_temp);
    }
}
```

In **MainActivity**,  I have the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

                List<Sms> lst = getAllSms();
                Intent iti=new Intent(getBaseContext(),TempActivity.class);
                startActivity(iti);

            }


        }
    });
}


public List<Sms> getAllSms() {
    List<Sms> lstSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();
    Sms objSms = new Sms();
    Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();

    Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, null, null, null);
    this.startManagingCursor(c);
    int totalSMS = c.getCount();

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {

            objSms = new Sms();
            objSms.setId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")));
            objSms.setAddress(c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
            objSms.setMsg(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
            objSms.setReadState(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("read")));
            objSms.setTime(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")));
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).contains("1")) {
                objSms.setFolderName("inbox");
            } else {
                objSms.setFolderName("sent");
            }

            lstSms.add(objSms);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    c.close();

    return lstSms;
}
```

So, on click of button (textView), I am reading sms from device and once this is done, I am launching the TempActivity. This works fine and activity is launched. But when in my TempActivity I press back button, the app crashes and I get the following error:

```
Unable to resume activity {com.myProject/com.myProject.MainActivity}: android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.
```

Comment: @NileshRathod Thanks, but I tried that, it still doesn't work.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24258376/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod The question seems to be quite different, although the error is similar. I am not doing anything in TempActivity, its just basic blank activity.

Comment: in which line you are getting error also share whole exception and whole `MainActivity` code

Comment: try creating a final instance from main activity and call getBaseContext() from that instance.

Comment: @NileshRathod Updated the question and added complete MainActivity

Comment: Try setting your cursor null when you close it.

Comment: @Alan Sorry, I didn't get what you mean by setting cursor to null.

Comment: @helloworld Cursor c = null

Comment: @Alan Thanks, it worked. Instead of `c.close()` I did `c = null`. But shouldn't the cursor be closed after reading all the SMSs?

Comment: @helloworld keep closing it and setting it to null too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to remove this line

```
this.startManagingCursor(c)
```

This method was deprecated in API level 11, I think problem is this line and you don't need this function at all. This method try to manage your Cursor but it not aware for life cycle and crash happen

And it is better to don't use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `BaseContext`

Instead of that Use this

```
Intent iti=new Intent(MainActivity.this,TempActivity.class);
iti.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: @helloworld try to remove hole line and retry.

Comment: Thanks, but still same error. I have edited and added complete MainActivity code.

Comment: @helloworld did you change your intent ? and still same error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189308/discussion-between-radesh-and-helloworld).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your cursor to null after you close it.

```
c.close();
c=null;
```

Comment: Thanks, but  this doesn't work. If I do c.close() and then c= null, it doesnt work. Just doing =null works.

Comment: Try setting it null before closing, then.

Comment: No, that also crashes the app. Setting c = null, makes c null then it has no close method.